# Puppeteer Proxy

Tags: node.js, http-proxy, puppeteer

I'm attempting to use puppeteer with my own proxy but I cannot seem to get it to work. 
My proxy looks like the following:

```
import * as h from 'http';
import * as hp from 'http-proxy';
import * as url from 'url';

const proxy = hp.createProxyServer({});
proxy.on('proxyReq', function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
    res.setHeader("Derp", "1231");
});

proxy.listen(8899);

h.createServer(function (req, res) {
    const reqUrl = url.parse(req.url);
    const targetHost = reqUrl.protocol + "//" + reqUrl.host;
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: targetHost });
}).listen(3111);
```

Then when I launch my browser I give the following properties

```
const baseOptions: LaunchOptions = {
        args:
            [
                "--no-sandbox",
                "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
                `--proxy-server=localhost:3111`,
            ],
        timeout: 0,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
    };
```

It fails on the `goto` command with the following error

```
Error: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE at http://natashaskitchen.com/
    at navigate (.../node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:598:37)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

If anyone has any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: what is the output of `curl -x localhost:3111 http://httpbin.org/ip`? does it show your ip or the proxy? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `page.authenticate()` to authenticate your proxy

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.18.1&show=api-pageauthenticatecredentials

This is how I use Puppeteer with authenticated proxy and it works great!

```
const launchConfig = {
      headless: true,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      args: [`--proxy-server=11.321.4.23:8080`],
    };

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchConfig);
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.authenticate({
      username: 'brucewayne',
      password: 'darkknight',
    });
```